# Do Google Maps usage limits apply when using own photos?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm part of a team looking to implement an open source package such that anyone can take a series of panoramic photos and create a virtual tour via the street view API.

However, before I start, I'd like some clarification on just what the usage limits apply to.  We'll be hosting the photos on our own server, but using Google's API.  Does the request limit apply in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

> Use of the Google Street View Image API is subject to a query limit of
>   1000 unique (different) image requests per viewer per day.

With V3 when you are handling the custom image which requires handling custom requests

check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomPanoramaMethod

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/#usage_limits

You will probably want to do a proof of concept and test it to see.

The best answer to your question is to email google and ask them.